# What is the best practice for disabling a cache request from the Full Page Cache (FPC) in magento (enterprise)

Tags: magento, config, enterprise

I wish to remove the following setting:

```
<cms>enterprise_pagecache/processor_default</cms>
```

... from the config.xml of the core  / Enterprise /  PageCache / config.xml file so that the home page will not be cached, (because we have a complicated custom store switch in place).

Since this value is not stored in core_config_data I am unsure of the best way to override the out of the box value.   The comments above the line in the core file do hint that it is not actually bad practice to edit this file, however, can I open this to the community to see what they think?

PS = This is a multi website setup with a custom store switcher.

Answer (score 0):

Hole punching is what it sounds like you may need.

Add a etc/cache.xml file with a `<config>` root to your module. (see Enterprise/PageCache/etc/cache.xml). Choose a unique [placeholder] name.

The placeholders/[placeholder]/block node value must match the class-id of your custom dynamic block, e.g. mymodule/custom

The placeholders/[placeholder]/container node value is the class to generate the content dynamically and handle block level caching

The placeholders/[placeholder]/placeholder node value is a unique string to mark the dynamic parts in the cached page

placeholders/[placeholder]/cache_lifetime is ignored, specify a block cache lifetime in the container’s `_saveCache()` method if needed

Implement the container class and extends `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Abstract`. Use `_renderBlock()` to return the dynamic content.

Implement the `_getCacheId()` method in the container to enable the block level caching. Use cookie values instead of model ids (lower cost).

One last note: You DON’T have the full Magento App at your disposal when `_renderBlock()` is called. Be as conservative as possible.

SOURCE: http://tweetorials.tumblr.com/post/10160075026/ee-full-page-cache-hole-punching

Comment: This is a good explanation of how placeholders and FPC work, but I am trying to stop the request to cms/index/index from being cached ever since cookies and session are not being updated correctly in models and controllers when FPC is on.   I dont see that the logic which I wish to enforce can be transferred into a block and hence encapsulated in a container.